# About execution order of onclick in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a question about the execution order of the onclick attribute in JavaScript.

I would like to know why the function written after form submission is executed.
Why is it not run from above?

```html
<form action="post" name="formTest">
    <button type="button" onclick="A(B)" id="test">test</button>
</form>
<script>
    function A(B) {
        formTest.submit();
        B();
    }

    function B() {
            window.alert('Function B');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to describe what you expect to see vs what you actually see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form submissions, and `formTest.submit()`, are asynchronous, meaning they are executed but the browser doesn't wait for them to finish before moving on to the next line of code.

Because submitting a form is a relatively long process compared to firing an alert (ie: you have to make a HTTP request and receive a response from the server) the browser runs `formTest.submit()`, runs `alert()`, then the submission completes from the background.

Comment: The navigation is async. It must be e.g. to let events like `beforeunload` fire. The form submission (url check, formdata construction etc.) is done synchronously, so you can't modify it after the submission started.